# jQuery: Appending multiple elements from .load() after the last occurrence of a specific class element on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a listing page and I am trying to create a "Load More Items" functionality. I'm attempting to use .load() to append all ".vehicleListing" elements from another page url (the second listing page) and add them after the last occurrence of a a div with the class of "vehicleListing".

Page 1:

```
<div class="overview-feature-1">
    <div class="vehicleListing">1</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">2</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">3</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">4</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">5</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">6</div>

    <div class="controls"></div>
    <div class="additional-controls"></div>
</div>
```

Page 2:

```
<div class="overview-feature-1">
    <div class="vehicleListing">7</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">8</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">9</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">10</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">11</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">12</div>

    <div class="controls"></div>
    <div class="additional-controls"></div>
</div>
```

Desired Result:
Page 1 after "Load More" functionality is executed:

```
<div class="overview-feature-1">
    <div class="vehicleListing">1</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">2</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">3</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">4</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">5</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">6</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">7</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">8</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">9</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">10</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">11</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">12</div>

    <div class="controls"></div>
    <div class="additional-controls"></div>
</div>
```

This is what I have so far, but it keeps adding it inside the last vehicleListing div instead of after it.

```
$(".vehicleListing").after().last().load('page2url' + ' .vehicleListing');
```

Can someone point out why it's inserting inside the last div instead of after it, and how I can correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:
Add an empty div after the last **vehicleListing** in your first file

```
<div class="overview-feature-1">
    <div class="vehicleListing">1</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">2</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">3</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">4</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">5</div>
    <div class="vehicleListing">6</div>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <div class="controls"></div>
    <div class="additional-controls"></div>
</div>
```

And change your JS

```
  $("#container").load('http://aba.bbtj.dev/test2.html' + ' .vehicleListing', function(){
    $('#container').replaceWith(function() {
     return $('.vehicleListing', this);
    });
    $( '<div id="container"></div>' ).insertAfter( ".vehicleListing:last" );
  });
```

This will load the new vehicles in the empty div, and then remove that div and keep the new vehicles (using the replaceWith function).

Then we re-add the empty div to be able to add more vehicule.

Comment: This does exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Load documntation:
>
> Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

```
$(".vehicleListing").after().last()
```

Targets the last `vehicleListing` div.

You can try smething like:

```
$.load('page2url' + ' .vehicleListing').insertAfter(".vehicleListing:last");
```

Comment: Afaik, load does not exist on the $ namespace.  It exists on the $.fn namespace.  Also the use of insertAfter() off of an async method like load() is most likely non-functioning logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your probably going to have to go about this differently.  As mentioned, load() takes the response and loads it into the element it is operating upon.  Since it replaces the contents, it doesn't really fit what you are trying to do which is to append additional content to an existing element.  Your best bet is to probably use an ajax method instead.

```
$.get('page2url' + ' .vehicleListing', function(data){
    $(".vehicleListing").last().after(data);
});
```